# Inject dependencies into index without bower+wiredep

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, bower, wiredep

currently i'm using gulp + bower with wiredep to inject my dependencies into my HTML file. It all works pretty well but i'm having some problems with newer versions that don't support bower anymore.

Having that said, I would love to just drop bower completely and use the node_modules files instead. Is there anything that works like wiredrep but instead uses package.json to get my dependencies?

thank you all

Comment: Aren't you using any kind of bundling?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Do you any kind of module bundler like rollup, browserify, or webpack? Or a script loader like require.js or SystemJS? Or do you just have a script tag for each dependency?

Comment: right now i have 1 script tag for each script that I then use useref to bundle then. Anyway I resolved this issue. Thx anyway

Comment: If you resolved your issue, please consider answering your own question in a way that is helpful to future viewers.

Comment: Please post what you did to resolve your issue.